# Facebook sharer for single page application- without a backend implemenation

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

We are building a single page front end only application. The application lets the user configure a product and share on facebook a url to the product configured. The application can rebuild the complete product again using the information present in the url. Based on the configuration, the title and the description. along with the image to be shared changes. The issue is,  I update the meta tags dynamically based on params present in the url. Since, the sharer.php takes in only the url as a parameter (u=link), and looks at the OG meta tags, they are empty if you view src of the page. The share functionality does not work in our case, since the description, title, image changes from user to user.

Is there way to achieve this? If OG meta tags are updated dynamically, the api should intelligent enough to understand and read the meta tags. There was a way to pass parameters earlier in the request so that OG meta tags are not read and information was derived from the url params, but new FB apis do not support parameterized request anymore.

Comment: Why doesn't your page return the appropriate meta tags for the URL parameters?

Comment: _“I update the meta tags dynamically based on params present in the url”_ – and what exactly does that look like?

Comment: can you post an example URL where we can see this working?

Comment: Our application is not yet live, but lets say our url is : www.myapplication.com/build?xcod=123&icod=EB10. Now our application, in $(document).ready, reads xcol and icol, makes a call to an external service, fetches some info, and then updates og:title, og:image, og:description meta tags.  But when I share the url - sharer.php?u=www.myapplication.com/build?xcod=123&icod=EB10, in share dialog box, I do not see updated description, title, or share image url.

Comment: I update the meta tag, like this - $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content','http:/myapplication.com' + buildImage.path);

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how that can be achieved, would really appreciate your help in this.